# Java stream API - создание коллекции

Tags: java, java-stream

Есть класс A

```
class A {

  List<B> bList;
  public List<B> getBList() {
    return bList;
  }

}
```

И есть коллекция из объектов A.

Как можно при помощи функции toCollect() получить коллекцию из других коллекций bList

Answer (score 1):

Не очень понятно, какой метод `toCollect()` имеется в виду, но в общем случае делается как-то так:

```
List<List<B>> bLists = aList.stream().map(A::getBList).collect(Collectors.toList());
```